# Dummy API for a Django Test

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a booking app that can deal with both local and remote API bookings. Our logic —for (eg) pricing and availability— follows two very different pathways. We obviously need to test both.

But running regular tests against a remote API is slow. The test environment provided manages a response in 2-17 *seconds*. It's not feasible to use this in my pre_commit tests. Even if they sped that up, it's never going to be fast and will always require a connection to pass.

But I still need to test our internal logic for API bookings.

Is there some way that within a test runner, I can spin up a little webserver (quite separate to the Django website) that serves a reference copy of their API. I can then plug that into the models we're dealing with and query against that locally, at speed.

What's the best way to handle this?

Again, I need to stress that this reference API should not be part of the actual website. Unless there's a way of adding views that only apply at test-time. I'm looking for clean solutions. The API calls are pretty simple. I'm not looking for verification or anything like that here, just that bookings made against an API are priced correctly internally, handle availability issues, etc.

Answer (score 0):

for your test porpuse you can mock api call functions.

you can see more here:

https://williambert.online/2011/07/how-to-unit-testing-in-django-with-mocking-and-patching/